# jquerymobile dynamic select options end up with wrong selected value

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When I step through the tap event code, I see the exact behavior that I expect, set ddlValues to proper selected option) but after the event bubbling code is run after my code, the selected option is set back to the first option everytime.
Here is all the code in the page only showing relevant as I've checked that no other code of mine is running because events get fired.

This select control is on a page2 of a two page page jquery mobile style.
In tap event, last event, note the changepage method, after which I start my setting that gets overridden.

Can't find an event that runs late enough to reset the value, because that would solve it since I have the values I want set in global hdn control.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      function GetPricing(cardid) {
        var prices = $('#ddlValues');
        var cardp = {};
        cardp.cardid = cardid;
        var datax = JSON.stringify(cardp);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "cardedit.aspx/GetPricing",
          data: datax,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (response) {
            prices.empty();
            $.each(response.d, function (index, item) {
              prices.append(new Option(item.Name, item.ID));
            });
            prices.selectmenu("refresh");
          },
          error: function () {
            alert("Failed to load data");
          }
        });
      }
      function GetDetail(id) {
        var cardd = {};
        cardd.id = id;
        var datax = JSON.stringify(cardd);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "cardedit.aspx/GetDetail",
          data: datax,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (response) {
            var vals = response.d;
            $('#txtNumber').val(vals[0]);
            $('#txtPrice').val(vals[1]);
            $('#txtTrade').val(vals[2]);
            $('#txtSell').val(vals[3]);
            $('#txtWholesale').val(vals[4]);
          },
          error: function () {
            alert("Failed to load data");
          }
        });
      }
      function GetDetailx(id) {
        var cardd = {};
        cardd.id = id;
        var datax = JSON.stringify(cardd);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "cardedit.aspx/GetDetailx",
          data: datax,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (response) {
            var vals = response.d;
            $('#txtPrice').val(vals[0]);
            $('#txtTrade').val(vals[1]);
            $('#txtSell').val(vals[2]);
            $('#txtWholesale').val(vals[3]);
          },
          error: function () {
            alert("Failed to load data");
          }
        });
      }
      $('#ddlCards').change(function () {
        var cardid = $(this).attr('value');
        GetPricing(cardid);
      });
      $('#ddlValues').change(function () {
        var priceid = $(this).attr('value');
        $('#hdnPriceid').val(priceid)
        GetDetailx(priceid);
      });
      $('.cardxx').on('tap', function () {
        var x = $(this);
        var id = x.data("id");
        $('#hdnCardid').val(id);
        var cardid = x.data("cardid");
        var priceid = x.data("priceid");
        $('#hdnPriceid').val(priceid);
        var pagex = $('#page2');
        $.mobile.changePage(pagex);
        var cards = $('#ddlCards');
        cards.val(cardid);
        cards.selectmenu("refresh");
        GetPricing(cardid);
        GetDetail(id);
        var pricexs = $('#ddlValues');
        pricexs.val(priceid);
        pricexs.selectmenu("refresh", true);
        event.stopPropagation();
      });
    });
  </script>
```

After my code is run I see jquery and jquerymobile code running, but don't understand it enough to see why it is resetting ddlValues back to first option.

If I postpone the set select option a quarter of a second the problem is solved, but that
seems too crude.